# Can I set alerts for an AD group without having exchange?

Tags: 2013, security, distribution-lists

We have our security groups coming from AD on the AD import.  A user wants to set an alert on a list to notify the group when something changes.  The group is a global security group.  I can set the email address and rerun the sync, but every time I add the group to the alert, I get the message "The following users do not have e-mail addresses specified: "

I know the AD import is working but I'm thinking the missing element here is that we don't have Exchange.  Can a non-Exchange environment have a security group added to an alert and have everyone in that group be notified?

Comment: is your group email enabled?

Comment: @WaqasSarwarMCSE Where would I check that?

Comment: if you added the email address then it is already email enable...check this http://blog.gavin-adams.com/2007/10/26/sending-alerts-to-groups-in-sharepoint-2007/

Comment: I see the email in AD, but when I drill down to the group in SP, I don't see the email field set.  I've been doing incremental AD updates.  Would this have to be a full synch in order to pull  this property over?  Is there a Powershell command to update a pulled AD group's email?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone in a similar environment, this is what you do:

Add the AD group to any SharePoint group you have on the site.

Since you can't set the user properties of a group through the Central Administration Tool, do it through Powershell.  Fire up a command line with the SharePoint Powershell commands added and do:

```
Set-SPUser -Identity 'domain\groupname' -web URLTOSharepoint -Email 'EmailAddressHere'
```

After that, I went back into SP and clicked on the group name and the email appeared there. I could then set email alerts for that group.